# Add extra button to django model admin page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is what my admin page for 1 of my models currently look like:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to add a button next to the `Add note` button which will allow me to perform a django action. Is there a way I can get this done? I just want the button to scan the notes and delete the empty ones, but that part I can work out. I just want to know how I can add a button next to `Add note` so I can link this to django.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can override the default template (`change_list.html`) for your application. Simply create a file named `change_list.html` under `my_app/templates/admin/my_app/my_model/` folder consisting of the following:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'my_custom_url' %}" class="addlink">
      {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}My Custom Action{% endblocktrans %}
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    {% url cl.opts|admin_urlname:'add' as add_url %}
    <a href="{% add_preserved_filters add_url is_popup to_field %}" class="addlink">
      {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
    </a>
  </li>
{% endblock %}
```

You can then write a view that implements the required action (scan & delete notes, in your case) and add it to your `urls.py` using `name='my_custom_url'`.

Do not forget to redirect the flow to the admin page at the end of your view using something like:

```
return redirect('admin:myapp_mymodel_changelist')
```